# Solving a BVP on a fixed non-uniform grid in python without interpolating

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, differential-equations

I am aware of `scipy.solve_bvp` but it requires that you interpolate your variables which I do not want to do.

I have a boundary value problem of the following form:

`y1'(x) = -c1*f1(x)*f2(x)*y2(x) - f3(x)`

`y2'(x) = f4(x)*y1 + f1(x)*y2(x)`

`y1(x=0)=0, y2(x=1)=0`

I have values for `x=[0, 0.0001, 0.025, 0.3, ... 0.9999999, 1]` on a non-uniform grid and values for all of the variables/functions at only those values of `x`.

How can I solve this BVP?

Comment: Looking at the documentation I don't see anything about a regular mesh, just a strictly increasing one.  The examples all use `linspace`, but that's probably for convenience.

Comment: @hpaulj the problem is that they want to change the mesh throughout the calculation, requiring me to interpolate all of my variables to the new mesh. That's why it returns `x: Nodes of the final mesh.`

Comment: In that case, you'll have to dig into that code to see how it works, and why it creates the new mesh.

Comment: @hpaulj That sounds difficult. I'll give fake internet points to anyone who does it for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a new function, and I don't have it on my `scipy` version (0.17), but I found the source in `scipy/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py` (github).

The relevant pull request is https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6025, last April.

It is based on a paper and MATLAB implementation,

```
       J. Kierzenka, L. F. Shampine, "A BVP Solver Based on Residual
       Control and the Maltab PSE", ACM Trans. Math. Softw., Vol. 27,
       Number 3, pp. 299-316, 2001.
```

The `x` mesh handling appears to be:

```
while True:
    ....
    solve_newton
    ....
    insert_1, = np.nonzero((rms_res > tol) & (rms_res < 100 * tol))
    insert_2, = np.nonzero(rms_res >= 100 * tol)
    nodes_added = insert_1.shape[0] + 2 * insert_2.shape[0]

    if m + nodes_added > max_nodes:
        status = 1
        if verbose == 2:
            nodes_added = "({})".format(nodes_added)
            print_iteration_progress(iteration, max_rms_res, m,
                                     nodes_added)
    ...
    if nodes_added > 0:
        x = modify_mesh(x, insert_1, insert_2)
        h = np.diff(x)
        y = sol(x)
```

where `modify_mesh` add nodes to `x` based on:

```
insert_1 : ndarray
    Intervals to each insert 1 new node in the middle.
insert_2 : ndarray
    Intervals to each insert 2 new nodes, such that divide an interval
    into 3 equal parts.
```

From this I deduce that

- you can track the addition of nodes with the `verbose` parameter
- nodes are added, but not removed.  So the out mesh should include all of your input points.
- I assume nodes are added to improve resolution in certain segments of the problem

This is based on reading the code, and not verified with test code.  You may be the only person to be asking about this function on SO, and one of the few to have actually used it.